# How to set an event handler for an item (QTableWidget) being enabled/disabled?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a QTableWidget that gets enabled and disabled depending on certain data.

I have a button I want to be enabled when the QTableWidget is enabled, and disabled when the widget is disabled.

Is there any event handler that would let me do this?
Such as (and this does not work):

```
    myTable.changeEvent.connect(lambda: print("test"))
```

Ideally in the above code, 'test' would be printed every time the table gets enabled or disabled.

Comment: Since you're already enabling/desabling on your own, can't you just create a signal for that and emit it?

Comment: I could but theres a little more to it than the base case i described. It just makes the code a lot messier and im trying to avoid that.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is that the moment you deactivate the QTableWidget you also deactivate the button (or use a signal to transmit the information).

Instead, another solution is to use an event filter that allows to emit a signal every time the widget's state changes and then use that information to change the button's state.

```py
import random
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class EnableHelper(QtCore.QObject):
    enableChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(bool)

    def __init__(self, widget):
        super().__init__(widget)
        self._widget = widget
        self.widget.installEventFilter(self)

    @property
    def widget(self):
        return self._widget

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if obj is self.widget and event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.EnabledChange:
            self.enableChanged.emit(self.widget.isEnabled())
        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(5, 4)
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Hello world")

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.table)
        lay.addWidget(self.button)

        helper = EnableHelper(self.table)
        helper.enableChanged.connect(self.button.setEnabled)

        self.test()

    def test(self):
        self.table.setEnabled(random.choice([True, False]))
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(1000, self.test)


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Widget()
    win.show()
    ret = app.exec_()
    sys.exit(ret)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Note:** changeEvent is not a signal so you should not use connect as this is a class method. Also it is not good to use it if you only want to detect if the widget changes state from enabled to disabled, or vice versa, since this is also called in other cases.